# How to make a Flutter DrawerHeader fixed?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a Drawer but somehow I cannot find any way to make its DrawerHeader stay fixed (while the items below keep scrolling). Tried Expanded, Flex, etc but somehow I'm missing something. This is the working code, but the header will scroll up with the items in the listview below

```
Widget _drawerList(BuildContext context) {

  return Drawer(
      elevation: 20.0,
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 120.0,
            child: DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orange),
              child: Text('HEADER'),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                title: Text("ITEM 1"),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("ITEM 2"),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("ITEM 3"),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("ITEM 4"),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("ITEM 5"),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("ITEM 6"),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("ITEM 7"),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("ITEM 8"),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("ITEM 9"),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("ITEM 10"),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("ITEM 11"),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("ITEM LAST"),
              ),
            ],
          )
         ],
      ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
Widget _drawerList(BuildContext context) {
  return Drawer(
    elevation: 20.0,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: 120,
          child: DrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orange),
            child: Text('HEADER'),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(...),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I tried a lot of things included Expanded but the key it was to use Column as the parent to both widgets. Using crossAlignment in the Column I was able to fit the whole width for the header.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Column as Parent View instead of ListView then replace Column with ListView inside so you header stick to it's place and Items are scrollable.

Comment: Yep that seems to be the way. I tried that in a moment but had some trouble below with the Tiles. Also, I couldn't get the header to fit its width but now I done it. Have to study about layouts a little more!